# Show/Hide a div when scrolling with "prototype"

Tags: prototypejs

Is there any chance to give us a script working with prototype (scriptaculous and effects) like the one on:`http://jsfiddle.net/alextercete/ShPXJ/` (made with with jQuery)

```
<style>
#someDiv {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: red;}
</style>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
var $someDiv = $("#someDiv"),
    top = $(this).scrollTop();

if (top > 200) {
    $someDiv.show();
} else {
    $someDiv.hide();
}});</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form the script could be this:

```js
Event.on(window, 'scroll', function() {
    Element.toggle('someDiv', pageYOffset > 200);
});
```

<sup>([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmsLbzhp/) - note, a new inline style is necessary)</sup>

But if you wanted to add some effects, which is reasonable, then there is a complication.  The page scroll event fires repeatedly which could trigger multiple effects on the same element and make a mess.  Scriptaculus lets you pass options to [fix](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-queues/) this:

```js
var options = {queue: {position: 'end', scope: 'demo', limit: 1}};
Event.on(window, 'scroll', function() {
    (pageYOffset > 200 ? Effect.Appear : Effect.Fade)('someDiv', options);
});
```

<sup>([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmsLbzhp/1/))</sup>

Instead of [Appear](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-appear/) and [Fade](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-fade/) methods you could instead use [BlindUp](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-blindup/) and [BlindDown](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-blinddown/), or [SlideUp](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-slideup/) and [SlideDown](https://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-slidedown/).